# Exporting datatable to a particular worksheet of an existing excel workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I have an excel workbook with two sheets. The second sheet contains two columns which provides data for dropdown list in sheet1. Now, I want to generate second sheet's data from database. 
So, basically I want to insert data in an excel file in a particular sheet from database/gridview. Is there easier way to do that using **itextSharp** in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have installed Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Office.

After that create common .NET project and add the reference to COM object Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll via 'Add Reference..' dialog.

Disclaimer: I wrote the code without checking it.

```
//open the workbook and set the worksheet 
Application excel = new Application();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
Worksheeet ws = wb.sheets("WorkSheetName");

int i = 1; //used to track the column sin the excel sheet

//loop through datagrid
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourDataGrid)
{
    //Cell[row, col]
    ws.Cell[i, 1] = row.Cells[1]  //assuming the location of item1
    ws.Cell[i, 2] = row.Cells[2]  //assuming the location of item2
    i++;
}

//save and close 
wb.Close(true);
```

Comment: Microsoft itself [discourage use of Office in server side scenarios](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) like Asp.Net. the linked page gives a list of reasons for this. First of all, the need to install excel in the server. In many case, this is even not an option

Answer (score 0):

This will dump the contents of a GridView into your Excel file.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel; 

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cnn ;
            string connectionString = null;
            string sql = null;

            connectionString = "data source=servername;initial catalog=databasename;user id=username;password=password;";
            cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cnn.Open();
            sql = "SELECT * FROM Product";
            SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            dscmd.Fill(ds);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel.Application xlApp ;
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0; 

            for (i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount  - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount  - 1; j++)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
                }
            }

            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("csharp.net-informations.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();

            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);

            MessageBox.Show("Excel file created , you can find the file c:\\csharp.net-informations.xls");
        }

        private void releaseObject(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
                obj = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                obj = null;
                MessageBox.Show("Exception Occured while releasing object " + ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

You can load a GridView from SQL Server in the following manner.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connetionString;
        SqlConnection connection;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataSet changes;
        string Sql;
        Int32 i; 

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            Sql = "select * from Product";
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, connection);
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show (ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
                changes = ds.GetChanges();
                if (changes != null)
                {
                    adapter.Update(changes);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Changes Done");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, you can push the data from SQL Server straight into Excel (or pull it into Excel from SQL Server).

```
Function ImportSQLtoRange

The function inserts SQL Server data to the target Excel range using ADO.

Function ImportSQLtoRange(ByVal conString As String, ByVal query As String, _
    ByVal target As Range) As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    ' Object type and CreateObject function are used instead of ADODB.Connection,
    ' ADODB.Command for late binding without reference to
    ' Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library

    ' ADO API Reference
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086(v=VS.85).aspx

    ' Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim con As Object
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    con.ConnectionString = conString

    ' Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim cmd As Object
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    cmd.CommandText = query
    cmd.CommandType = 1         ' adCmdText

    ' The Open method doesn't actually establish a connection to the server
    ' until a Recordset is opened on the Connection object
    con.Open
    cmd.ActiveConnection = con

    ' Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rst As Object
    Set rst = cmd.Execute

    If rst Is Nothing Then
        con.Close
        Set con = Nothing

        ImportSQLtoRange = 1
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Integer

    Set ws = target.Worksheet

    ' Column Names
    For col = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
        ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column + col).Value = rst.Fields(col).Name
    Next
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column), _
        ws.Cells(target.row, target.Column + rst.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True

    ' Data from Recordset
    ws.Cells(target.row + 1, target.Column).CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    con.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

    ImportSQLtoRange = 0

End Function
```

Code comments:

```
The query parameter can contain a SELECT or EXECUTE query.
The resulting data will be inserted starting from the top left cell of the target range.
Using Object types and the CreateObject function instead of direct use of ADO types
lets to avoid setting ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library references on user computers.
This code works in Microsoft Excel 2003-2016.
Always use Set Nothing statements for ADODB.Connection and ADODB.Recordset objects to free resources.
```

See the link below for more ideas on how to do similar types of things.

https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-sql-server-import-export-using-vba.htm#SQLServerDataImporttoExcelusingADO